# How to use the NavigationService.Navigate inside a CustomMessageBox Dismissed event handler?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am using the `CustomMessageBox` control from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone. When passing an anonymous callback (a 'delegate' in MS speak?) as [suggested in the tutorials](http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/) I reference a member of the page's partial class defined in the code-behind file. This builds and deploys but crashes when I reach the logic at runtime.

I noticed from the VS debugger that the scope inside the callback only contains members from the XAML side of the page partial class and not the members from the code-behind file. This means that the member I refer to is not in the scope (even though Intellisense is fine with it). Moreover I cannot use `NavigationService.Navigate` inside the callback.

How do I call code within the containing class from the callback?

Here is the code,

```
        // This is a member of the partial class which inherits from 
        // PhoneApplicationPage
        private void cancelBtn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {

            if ((this.nameTextBox.Text != String.Empty) || (bool)this.protectCheckBox.IsChecked)
            {
                CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
                {
                    Caption = "Confirm leave page",
                    Message = "You have entered some profile data which will be lost if you leave this page. Are you sure you want to leave this page?",
                    LeftButtonContent = "no",
                    RightButtonContent = "yes"
                };

                messageBox.Dismissed += (s1, e1) =>
                {
                    if (e1.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton)
                    {
                        // Both of these raise an exception ...
                        GoToProfilePage();
                        //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

                        // Inspecting the debugger here shows only half the expected 
                        // number of methods in the 'this' object - specifically only
                        // those defined in XAML

                    }
                };
                messageBox.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                // This works fine
                GoToProfilePage();
            }


        }
```

Where `GoToProfilePage()` is a method in the code-behind file.

This is the exception,

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=NullReferenceException
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.CustomMessageBox.ClosePopup(Boolean restoreOriginalValues)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.CustomMessageBox.c__DisplayClass4.b__1(Object s, EventArgs e)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Transition.OnCompleted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

**Update**

It looks like the code is executed, it is only when the delegate finishes that the null reference exception is raised so it may not be a problem with scope ...

Answer (score 1):

OK figured it out. The latest build of the Windows Toolkit .dll (which includes `CustomMessageBox`) needed a reference in my solution.

Apparently there is an older version of the Windows Toolkit which is included in the default references somewhere since both ContextMenu and CustomMessageBox worked at least partially beforehand which is very confusing ...

To add the updated reference, I built the .dll from the source in a separate project and copied it to my project. I added a reference from the Reference right-click menu in VS and browsed to the file in the `debug\bin` directory.

Comment: The same is happening to me, I added the october version of the toolkit via Nuget. I cannot make it work

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack is to comment line 657 of CustomMessageBox.cs file in the toolkit source code and compile again. Then reference this new dll in your app.

```
...
private void ClosePopup(bool restoreOriginalValues)
        {
            // Remove the popup.

            _popup.IsOpen = false;
            //_popup = null; <-- THIS IS LINE 657
...
```

There is an issue posted in http://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/10575